# .aspx file include itself, can someone explain?

Tags: c#, asp.net

From UserProfile.aspx file:

```
<td runat="server" class="CenterColumn">
    <AspNetSHliga:UserProfile runat="server" ID="Userinfo1" NAME="Userinfo1" />
</td>
```

Hi, I've got this code. "AspNetSHliga:UserProfile" generate a huge table that i need to edit it.
Problem is there's only one UserProfile.aspx file. And this is it.
This UserProfile.aspx somehow "include" itself just like in the code above. And generate the table. There's another one called UserProfile.cs where is Engine. But if I edit it, or even delete it(refresh server, rebuild project or whatever..). Table is still generating..

Is there something I missing? A looked everywhere. And there are only one UserProfile.aspx file.

Comment: what is AspNetSHliga defined as and what if you search for classes called UserProfile  ignoring the file names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it can't include itself, but you probably have a `UserControl` named UserProfile, which will have the file extension `.ascx` rather than `.aspx`. Look at the top of the file or web config to see where `AspNetSHliga` is referenced.

Comment: It can also be referenced in the Master page so that's another place to check.

Comment: I just found it. I searched through all project by heading name and ending .ascx and its really .ascx file named Skin-DisplayPlayerInfo.ascx
thanks for comments! :)